# How to use Handlebars helpers in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js

I have a helper for truncating words, but I don't know where to put it / how to use it.

I want {{name}} to be truncated. How should I proceed?

Thanks

**My helper (helper.js)**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper ('truncate', function (str, len) {
    if (str.length > len) {
        var new_str = str.substr (0, len+1);

        while (new_str.length) {
            var ch = new_str.substr ( -1 );
            new_str = new_str.substr ( 0, -1 );

            if (ch == ' ') {
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( new_str == '' ) {
            new_str = str.substr ( 0, len );
        }

        return new Handlebars.SafeString ( new_str +'...' ); 
    }
    return str;
});
```

**My view**

```
<script id="pin-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="row">
<img class="col-3 small-brand-avatar" src="{{photo_url}}" %>
  <ul class="quarter_padding_left col-8 listnone">
    <li>
      <h5 class="medium">{{name}}</h5></li>
    <li class="block left"><span class="lightgray">de</span> {{location}}</li>
    <li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>
```